# unexpected output of a program

Tags: c++, class

I have written a basic program in C++ as below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class asd {
  int a,b;
  public:

  asd(int a, int b): a(a),b(b){}

  void set(int a, int b) {
    a = a + a;
    b = b + b;
  } 

  void show() {
    cout<<"a: "<<a<<" b :"<<b<<"\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  asd v(5,4);
  v.show();
  v.set(1,6);
  v.show();
   
  return 0;
}
```

Its Output is quite surprising
a: 5 b: 4
a: 5 b: 4

Why the value of a and b didn't change. If I replace the set() function as below

```
void set(int x, int y) {
  a = a + x;
  b = b + y;
}
```

then the output is as expected:
a: 5 b: 4
a: 6 b: 10

Comment: Compile with the `-Wshadow` option (gcc/clang) and the compiler will warn you about your problems. (you can use `/W3` on VS). Always compile with **full warnings** enabled and include `-Wshadow` with gcc/clang.

Comment: Thanks, yes now I can see the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
a = a + a;
```

in the `set` function, all three instances of `a` is the *local argument varible* `a`, and not the member variable `a`.

A variable declared in a narrower scope *hides* variables of the same name in a wider scope. Here the narrow scope is the function and the wide scope is the object.

To explicitly use the member variable, you need to say so with `this->a`:

```
this->a = this->a + a;
```

Or

```
this->a += a;
```

Comment: May I suggest adding a little to say `asd(int a, int b): a(a),b(b){}` is a special case where `a(a)` has an implied `this->a(a)`.

Comment: I'd add, too, the technical explanation of the locally defined variable `a` *hiding* the class member `a`.